# How to create multiple rotated detent-like cutouts in the of a cylinder in OnShape?

Tags: cad, rotation

Imagine a thick-walled cylinder which is going to be 3D printed. I want to carve, say, ten identical detents in the top of the object, rotated around by 36 degrees. I know how to make one of these by creating a circle above the cylinder wall with the desired small arc reaching down into the top of the cylinder, and then remove extrude the circle. I want to avoid having to create ten of these super-carefully placed at 36 degrees from the another. Is there a way to rotationally replicate a sketch or extrude around a point or on a circle? I want to say something like: Do that thing again, at every 36° (or perhaps, ten times) around this circle.

Comment: Have you tried the **Circular pattern** option?